# Angularjs form issues. Form is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, forms

Hi I created a nested view form for my app.

It worked great...however I decided to add more pages to the form to extend it's functionality  (6 form pages stored in partials/formname.html etc.

The form will not appear. It's just a blank space.  Just the header/nav bar works.

I feel the issue lies with the script.js.   The console doesn't seem to throw up any errors.  I've spent all day trying to figure out why it won't run and I really could do with some help.  Thanks

Here's my plunker:  [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHLrmiGj7YenHgfM8KLb?p=info)

Here's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="financeApp">

<head>
 <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet"  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
 <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.10" data-semver="0.2.10" src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.10/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
 <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller = "demoCtrl">

  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
   <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
     <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
   </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
    <a ui-sref="form">Form</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: isState('contact') }">
    <a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h3 class="text-muted">Demo Page</h3>
 <br>
 <div ui-view=""></div>


 </body>

 </html>
```

and script.js

```
var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', [
  'ui.router' ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('form', {
          url: '/form',
          templateUrl: 'partials/form.html',
          controller: 'formCtrl'
        })






 //note the following are form's child states
          .state('form.goal', {
            url: '/goal',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formGoal.html',
            controller: 'formGoalCtrl'
          })
          .state('form.goalamount', {
            url: '/goalamount',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formGoalamount.html',
            controller: 'formGoalamountCtrl'
          })
          .state('form.risk', {
            url: '/risk',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formRisk.html',
            controller: 'formRiskCtrl'
          })

          .state('form.invest', {
            url: '/invest',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formInvest.html',
            controller: 'formInvestCtrl'
          })
          .state('form.fund', {
            url: '/fund',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formFund.html',
            controller: 'formFundCtrl'
          })
          .state('form.account', {
            url: '/account',
            templateUrl: 'partials/formAccount.html',
            controller: 'formAccountCtrl'
          })

        //contact state
        .state('contact', {
          url: '/contact',
          templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
          controller: 'contactCtrl'
        });
    }
  ])


financeApp.controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$location',
  function($scope, $state, $location) {
    $scope.isState = function(states) {
      return $state.includes(states);
    };
  }
])
 .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope',
'$state',
  function($scope, $state) {} ]) .controller('formCtrl', ['$scope',
'$state',
  function($scope, $state) {




 //This is to go to one of the child state of formCtrl. Here I choose
//it to go to profile state first.
    //optionally you can use parent property or "abstract = true".
    //or you can use $urlRedirect service.
    $state.go('.profile');
  }
]) .controller('formGoalCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {
    //just a simple function to go to the next state using $state.go()
    $scope.goToNextState = function(nextState){
      $state.go(nextState);
    }
  }
]) .controller('formGoalamountCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.goToNextState = function(nextState){
      $state.go(nextState);
    }
  }



]) .controller('formRiskCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.goToNextState = function(nextState){
      $state.go(nextState);
    }
  }



]) .controller('formInvestCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.goToNextState = function(nextState){
      $state.go(nextState);
    }
  }



]) .controller('formFundCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
  function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.goToNextState = function(nextState){
      $state.go(nextState);
    }
   }
    ]) .controller('formAccountCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
    function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.finished = function(){
      alert('Form Completed!')
     }
    }
   ]) .controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',
   function($scope, $state) {
     $scope.contact_str = "This is a string from contactctrl";
   }

    ]);
```

Comment: if you click the tabs in the plunker you get errors in the console, there are also lots of undefined is not a function messages logged...

Comment: But most of these errors are in the angular.js CDN code?   I can't seen any errors with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your states are not resolving is because your template url paths are incorrect given the files you are trying to reference. Each value of `templateUrl` must be the actual path to the file that contains the partial. In your example you do not have a directory named `partials/` under which your views reside. They are in the same directory as the rest of your files.

If you remove `'partials/'` from your `templateUrl`s then the states will resolve.

---

Some other advice and thoughts after looking through your code:

- In your top-level form controller you are redirecting to a child state called `.profile` which does not exist, so this is throwing an error.
- Using relative states in `$state.go()` can cause issues when the user manipulates state using the forward or back buttons. Using full state names such as `'form.goal'` instead of `'.goal'` will prevent this.
- You are setting up an otherwise redirect for the `home` state by attempting to route to `'/home'`; however, in order to default to the `home` state you must pass in the url of the home state, which is `'/'`. Please see my changes to your plunk for a working example below.
- Lastly, just as a suggestion, `ui.router` includes a directive named `uiSrefActive` which you can use in conjunction with `uiSref` to set the active class on a nav element. More info on that here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active

**Updated plunk:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/L9eCNpwpNHzZmKuY2V4J?p=preview

Comment: Perfect.  You took your time to explain and actually edited my plunker.  Thanks!